# iOS Zombie - can't figure out why object is released

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to debug some code that has a exc_bad_access crash. It appears I have a zombie, but I can't figure out why the object is being deallocated. It is a Unity3D project, built for iOS. The code in question is in a .mm file, so ObjectiveC++.

So Instruments shows the function that is being deallocated, but I don't really understand what is happening. The Responsible Caller is a function called LoadVideo, which is wrapped in an 'extern "C"'.  The code is below:

```
extern "C"
{
void LoadVideo()
{
    // get the current UIViewController
    UIViewController *viewController = UnityGetGLViewController();
    // create the videLoader object
    VideoLoaderUIObject * vidLoader = [VideoLoaderUIObject new];

    // start up our loading screen
    gSavingVideoAlert = [[CustomIOS7AlertView alloc] init];

    UIView* uiViewLoading = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 125)];

    UILabel* loadingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 40)];

    loadingLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    [loadingLabel setText:@"Loading videos\nPlease Wait..."];
    [loadingLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [loadingLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [loadingLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [loadingLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Trebuchet MS" size: 14.0f]];
    [uiViewLoading addSubview:loadingLabel];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

    // Adjust the indicator so it is up a few pixels from the bottom of the alert
    indicator.center = CGPointMake(uiViewLoading.bounds.size.width / 2, uiViewLoading.bounds.size.height - 50);
    [indicator startAnimating];

    [uiViewLoading addSubview:indicator];
    [gSavingVideoAlert setContainerView:uiViewLoading];

    [gSavingVideoAlert show];

    // open the media gallery
    [vidLoader startMediaBrowserFromViewController: viewController usingDelegate: vidLoader];

#ifdef DEBUG_LOGS
    NSLog(@"video path %@", [vidLoader VideoPath]);
#endif

}
}
```

The problem seems to be at this line:

```
[vidLoader startMediaBrowserFromViewController: viewController usingDelegate: vidLoader];
```

The vidLoader object is from a VideoLoaderUIObject class, defined as:

```
@interface VideoLoaderUIObject : UIImagePickerController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
    @private
    bool mIsUsingCam;
    NSMutableArray* mAssets;
    NSMutableArray *mVidIPod;
    NSMutableArray *mVidItems;
    std::vector<UIInterfaceOrientation> mVidOrientations;

    MyCustomViewController* mScrollViewController;
}
```

The output from Instruments is below:

[image]

What's stopping the vidLoader object being retained?

Comment: `vidLoader` goes out of scope at the end of the `LoadVideo` function. It will be deallocated at that time.

Comment: `vidLoader` may have to be a property and not a local variable (async method needing `vidLoader` after could cause this)